# HttpSession timeout

Tags: jsf, iframe, websphere, httpsession

i have a jsf application in which i have three frames,one for the header,one for side navigation and the other is the mainframe.I have built this in the spring framework.
I have a problem that when the HttpSession object gets timed out the apllication gets forwarded to the Login page(which is correct,and is the starting page of the app) but within the mainframe so i have a nested application.btw i am running this app in websphere and i can set the HttpSession timeout variable to a very high value so that this problem will occur less,but this is not a solution.
Any ideas on how i can get around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

iFrames are **really** a bad thing!

What I suggest is to use the [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) library, which allow you to *easily* create templates of pages. In your case, you will be able to create the three differents parts (header, navigation side and main page).

Once created, the result will be a single HTML page (i.e. no frames).
This way, you will not encounter your problem anymore.

You have [several articles](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/FaceletsArticles) that explains the main features of Facelets, including the templating.